# How to get the commit IDs from all the tags in a submodule?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, git-tag

I'm using the following command to get the tags in each of the submodules:

```
git submodule foreach git tag --sort=-taggerdate -l
```

But I'm not sure how to also get the commit IDs for each tag listed.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Submodule commit ID:

[image]

Tag commit ID, selected the matching one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems you want to list tags that point to commits in submodules where those commits in submodules correspond to a commit in the superproject. The simplest way is to checkout the commit (or a branch, or a tag) in the superproject, update submodules to checkout saved commits (every commit in the superproject stores commits to checkout in its submodules) and list tags in every submodule that point to submodule's `HEAD`:

```
git checkout --recurse-submodules master # or tag, or SHA1 in the superproject
git submodule foreach --recursive git tag --points-at=HEAD --format="%(refname:lstrip=2) %(objectname:short)"
```

`git tag` has an option [`--format="string"`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---formatltformatgt). For the list of field names see [`git help for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names).

Comment: @tadm123 What do you mean? With `git submodule foreach` you run `git tag` in every submodule, both `refname` and `objectname` are from submodules.

Comment: I wish I could explain it with pictures since I'm a begginner. For example, the submodule "AftCol" has a specific commit ID (`6f955c83`) in Gitlab and when going into its tags, the tags themselves had different commit IDs.  My overall goal is to figure out a way to only extract the commit ID of the tag inside the submodules that matches the commit ID of the submodule itself.

Comment: I updated the original post, hopefully it's easier to understand.

Comment: I suspect you use the term "the submodule itself" meaning the superproject (the parent project that contains the submodules). There is the superproject and its submodules; some submodules can be superprojects themselves and contain their own submodules recursively. With this corrected terminology what is your question? I guess you want to list tags that point to commits in submodules where those commits in submodules correspond to a commit in the superproject; you don't want to just list all tags in all submodules. Did I guess it right?

Comment: hi @phd, just a note that I thought it was working well but when looking at the commit ids of the tags closely, it's different than the ones in Gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

If commit date order is okay, rather than the tagger date:

```
git submodule foreach git log --no-walk --tags HEAD --oneline
```